# JVM спецификация составлена для всех реализаций Java или только для Hotspot'а?

Tags: java, jvm, hotspot

Все сторонние сборки java соответствуют общей jvm спеке? и, значит, по-идее, можно запускать на любой из них большинство java-приложений, даже разработанных для других jvm? Естественно, с потерями в производительности и т.д. Или jvm спека составлена лишь для хотспота и сторонние разработчики могут вообще реализовывать у себя все что захотят?

Comment: Вроде одна для всех была. Что-то поменялось? А почему обязательно потеря производительности? Может наоборот быстрей. Кстати есть jvm россейской разработки, а не каких-то опенсорсных индусов.

Comment: @Sergey ну, разные же сборки заточены для разных задач, и если приложение, требующее стабильного быстрого отклика и заточенное на сборку без GC, запустить на стандартной версии, то производительность в этом смысле пострадает.

Comment: Спецификация jvm не составлена под Hotspot, но Hotspot ей соответствует.  Есть, к примеру, IBM J9, которая не уступает первой по производительности. Плюс ещё множество других. Другое дело, что разработчики Hotspot имеют весомый голос при составлении новой спецификации.

Comment: @Темкатоже  , а что это значит для пользователей? Они могут запускать один и тот же jar на различных jvm?

Comment: Конечно могут. На то и существует спецификация.

Answer (score 0):

Для всех. Более того, если чья-то реализация JVM не соответствует спецификации и соответственно не проходит тест на соответствие этой спецификации посредством Technology Compatibility Kit (TCK) от Oracle, она не может называться JVM.